# Position textarea placeholder text on bottom

Tags: css, textarea, css-position, placeholder

I would like to position my textarea's placeholder text to the bottom of the textarea. Here is my code:

```
<p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Vos remarques"></textarea>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150%;
    resize:vertical;
}
```

Here is a full [codepen](http://codepen.io/elkhe89/pen/oBBGPj). I want to set the placeholders of textareas and inputs to be positioned near the bottom of the input and textareas. Currently, they are situated at the top of the text area and inputs. Is there any way to select the placeholders for the textarea and inputs and position near the bottom of the text area, near the border?

Comment: What do you mean *"put my placeholder textarea down"*?

Comment: sorry, I try to put a link .  http://codepen.io/elkhe89/pen/oBBGPj I mean to modify the position of the placeholder. I want to place it next to the border.

Comment: I edited the question so it's better suited for the site. Edit what you need to.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know a solution using only CSS to solve your problem.
I've created a solution using CSS + Javascript.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="placeholder">Vos remarques</label>
    <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-group {
    position: relative;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
    resize: vertical;
    position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
    bottom: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
    transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.feedback-input').on('input', function(){
        if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ) {
           $(this).siblings().css("opacity", "0");
        } else {
           $(this).siblings().css("opacity", "1");
        }
    });
});
```

[codepen.io Example](http://codepen.io/CesarCEARA/pen/wggydd)

Comment: Hi Cesar, I found a Css solution with: textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 100%;
    resize:vertical;
}

Comment: But now, I don't know how to put in bottom left

Comment: If it worked for you, fine. But for me your code did not work.
Maybe I did not understand what you need, good luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this @LindaAvernistan?